# How to access nested variables without error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have params that are of the structure:

```
data = {
  "messageId" => "B2YAx4rSMTZ4D8FJs1hsoV",
  "eventId" => "appointmentBooking.cancelled",
  "eventSchemaVersion" => 1.0,
  "eventInstanceOriginationDateTime" => "2019-11-06T19:24:10Z",
  "eventData" => {
    "siteId" => 232,
    "appointmentId" => 48761
  },
  "subdomain" => "api",
  "consultation" => {}
}
```

and I want to access the `siteId` and `appointmentId` for another function I find myself doing the following:

```
data = params['eventData']

if data.present?
  siteID = data['siteId']
  appointmentID = data['appointmentId']
end

if siteID and appointmentID
  # process this
end
```

This works sometimes, but if `!data.present?`, then `siteID` and `appointmentID` are undefined and that last `if` call will throw an error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `siteID'
```

Is there a better way to do this without pre-defining the variables directly after `data = params['eventData']`?

Comment: Do you mean for the variable holding your hash to be `params`, consider that `data` is set equal to `params['eventData']`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I don't know rails (Ruby doesn't have the method `present?`) but I understand `data.present?` will return `true` if `data` (`= params['eventData']`) is a non-empty hash, but also if it is a string with one character other than a space, a non-empty array, and so on. What exactly do wish to test? Do you want to ensure `params` has a key `eventData`? If it does do you want to ensure `data` is a hash? If so, I don't know why you would want to ensure its non-empty as your test is that two keys are present and both have truthy values. Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method. It returns `nil` if any intermediate step is `nil`.

```
appointment_id = data.dig('eventData', 'appointmentId')
#=> 48761

site_id = data.dig('eventData', 'siteId')
#=> 232
```

Then

```
if site_id && appointment_id
  # do_something
end
```

Comment: this was the "ah ha!" moment I was looking for.

Comment: This becomes tedious if `data['eventData']` has many keys. Personally I don't think `dig` is the right tool here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes you are right. But it’s good to use it for two keys :)

Answer (score 3):

You could explicitly check for the attributes you're hoping exist and then set the vars and process in one go:

```rb
data = params['eventData']

if data && data['siteId'] && data['appointmentId']
  siteID = data['siteId']
  appointmentID = data['appointmentId']
  # process this
end
```

Another option would be to save the `if` statement results into it's own var and then use that as the conditional for processing:

```rb
data = params['eventData']

process = if data.present?
  siteID = data['siteId']
  appointmentID = data['appointmentId']
end

if process
  # process this
end
```

Or another option would be to set the vars inline:

```rb
data = params['eventData']

if data && siteID = data['siteId'] && appointmentID = data['appointmentId']
  # process here
end
```

Comment: #1 is simple, but effective and reads well. #2 is not worth mentioning, imo, and #3 is wrong (because the OP, I think, wants to make sure that hash has a key `'eventData'`, but assumes its value is a hash if the key is present). Posting good answers at SO is in part knowing when to stop.

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the code with a check for `data`.

Comment: Keep in mind that different folks have different programming styles and that different solutions are often applicable in different scenarios, even within the same application. I enjoying seeing different ways of doing the same thing - even if one way is "better" than another. There's always room to learn a new way of doing something, even if it's not the right solution for your current problem. And what may look "wrong" to you may be preferable to someone else.

Answer (score -1):

We can write the following method:

```
def extract(schedule)
  siteId, appointmentId = 
    schedule["eventData"]&.values_at("siteId", "appointmentId")
end
```

If `schedule` does not have a key `"eventData"`, `sideId` and `appointentId` are both assigned a value of `nil`. If `schedule` does have a key `"eventData"` I have assumed that `schedule["eventData"]` is a hash and:

```
siteId = schedule["eventData"]["siteId"]
appointmentId = schedule["eventData"]["appointmentId"]
```

`&` is the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), which made its debut in Ruby v2.3. See also [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

This method is used as follows.

```
def doit(schedule)
  siteId, appointmentId = extract(schedule)
  if siteId && appointmentId
    # do something
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Here are some examples of the values returned by `extract`:

```
schedule = { "eventData"=>{ "siteId"=>232, "appointmentId"=>48761 } }
siteId, appointmentId = extract(schedule)
  #=> [232, 48761] 
siteId
  #=> 232 
appointmentId
  #=> 48761
```

```
schedule = { "eventData" => { "siteId" => 232 } }
siteId, appointmentId = extract(schedule)
  #=> [232, nil]
```

```
schedule = { "eventData" => {} }    
siteId, appointmentId = extract(schedule)
  #=> [nil, nil]
```

Comment: Scanning this answer is really confusing, and the examples are hard to read. But I've never used `:values_at` before, which I think is an interesting solution. Setting the vars with `siteID, appointmentID = data && params["eventData"]&.values_at("siteId", "appointmentId")` is a unique way of solving the problem.

Comment: @curiouscode, if my answer was confusing to you I failed in my objective. The only operative line of he method was of course the first; I included the two `puts` to help the reader understand what was going on in that first line. I adopted this form of answer on a whim. I appreciate your candor and will bear your advice in mind in future.

Comment: @curiouscode, I have modified my answer in the hopes that it is now more clear.